Android StudioでWear OSのEmpty Wear Appを選ぶとJavaが選択できません
Android StudioでWear OSのEmpty Wear Appを選ぶとJavaが選択できません。
ほかのプロジェクトを選ぶとlanguageで選択ができるのですが，ここだけlanguageの欄がでてきません。
ほかのサイトなど見ると出てきているので，これはどうしたらよいですか？
